# Tabs onclick jumps to top

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap, I have set an example up here: http://fixitup.com.au/clients/bootstrap/issue.html

Using scrollto for the main site, and also twitter bootstraps, tabs. I find that when you click on a tab the page jumps up.

I added `onclick="return false;"` to the href of the tabs.

Like:

```
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab" onclick="return false;">About Me</a></li>
<li><a href="#ripoffs" data-toggle="tab" onclick="return false;">My Ripoffs</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need scrollto and I need tabs... but I need to stop the page jumping, its driving me bonkers. Any suggestions ?

Added: the js for the scroll is in aruo.js code below:

```
// Any links with hash tags in them (can't do ^= because of fully qualified URL potential)
    $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {

        // Ensure it's a same-page link
        var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
        if (  locationPath == thisPath
            && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
            && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {

                // Ensure target exists
                var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
                if ($(target).length > 0) {

                    // Find location of target
                    var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                    $(this).click(function(event) {

                        // Prevent jump-down
                        event.preventDefault();

                        // Animate to target
                        $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1100, 'swing', function() {

                            // Set hash in URL after animation successful
                            location.hash = target;

                        });
                    });
                }
        }

    });

    // Use the first element that is "scrollable"  (cross-browser fix?)
    function scrollableElement(els) {
        for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
            var el = arguments[i],
            $scrollElement = $(el);
            if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
                return el;
            } else {
                $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
                var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
                $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
                if (isScrollable) {
                    return el;
                }
            }
        }
        return [];
    }

});
```

Comment: When do you want to scroll top ?

Comment: Scrollto is used on a few elements within the page, and also if you look on the back to top link in the footer. That example page I setup is purely a example setup, and not indicative of our physical page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just modify your selector so the scroll functions aren't applied to the tabs?

Depending on what attr, classes etc.. are available.

In this example I use the :not selector to exclude elements with the class "foo"

http://jsfiddle.net/vfJWk/1/

For your example, changing the selector to something like:

$('a[href*=#]:not([data-toggle="tab"])').each(function() {

Might work?

Comment: You're welcome! Selectors were kinda a mystery to me at first, but when you get the hang of them, you end up saving a LOT of code. Good luck with the rest!